# How to create a non blocking loop JS?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

I can not find the solution to this problem:

If you want to test the problem on your side on codepen or others, I leave you a small example:

You need an input type checkbox in html for the test and the JS code:

```
const array = []
 
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) array.push(i)
console.log(array.length)
```

In fact my problem is that during the execution of this code, if I click on the input, it will only be checked at the end of the execution of the for.

(which is very unpleasant for the customer rendering)

I know it is possible not to block the site while the calculation is done, but then how?

If you have the solution, I'm interested, even a track. Thank you !

Comment: This is a CPU-intensive task, and JS is single-threaded. It will block your thread no matter what. The only solution I can think of is to launch it in a [web worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), in a separate thread.

Comment: What front-end issue are you trying to solve that requires you to loop 10 million times?

Comment: Are you just looking for a more efficient way to create this array?  `const array = [...Array(10000000).keys()];` ?

Comment: @Andy Ah right! I forgot about the good old XY problems :)

Comment: It depends on how easily the calculation can be divided into smaller parts.
It's possible, for example, to do only 10000 each time, and use a setTimeout before doing the next 10000. Also, depending on the use, you may not need "eager evaluation". You may want to make a generator instead. 
Still, we don't know about your actual use case.

Comment: We could help you better if you gave a more concrete explanation of what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I just wanted to be oriented. that's why the code is simplified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this to use some kind of async pattern to not block the event loop too long.
For example create an async iterator like this:

```
async function doAsyncNTimes(n, process) {
    return new Promise(resolve=>{

        function helper(index) {
            if (index >= n) {
                resolve();
                return;
            }
            process(index);
            setTimeout(()=>{
                helper(index + 1);
            }
            )
        }
        let index = 0;
        helper(index);
    });
}

array = [];

doAsyncNTimes(10000, (index)=>{
    array.push(index);
}
).then((ret)=>{
    console.log(array)
});
```

This way you will only block event loop while one iteration is running, then scheduler the next iteration as soon as possible.
You can even make `process` async if you want, if it can be computationally heavy it can be beneficial. Processing millions of items will take a bit of time, but the UI will not blocked at all.

Comment: That would work correctly, but the overhead would be huge. Batching might be a good in-between solution, depending on what the person is really trying to do. Problem is that, right now, the question is a bit too abstract to give a proper answer.

Comment: You are right, this was only a direction. There is a lot of room to improve, but we don't know how complex the iterating code is. What is sure, this way it will be "more pleasant for customer rendering" as it will not block :) if the runtime of process is way below than one ms then it is trivial to modify this to do batch processing instead then scheduler the next batch, but as you said we have to know what do we wanna do.

Comment: Yes, I just wanted a lead, I don't want to give my work to others, thank you for your answers!